# Please tell me why $(y_j)$ is cofinally Cauchy?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I am having trouble understanding a small part from **theorem 3.2 ($1\implies 2$)** of this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864107003355) (*Between compactness and completeness, G. Beer*).

**Prerequisite:** (1) A sequence $(x_n)$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ called cofinally Cauchy if for $\epsilon>0~\exists~\mathbb N_0\text{ (infinite)}\subset\mathbb N$ such that $d(x_i,x_j)<\epsilon~\forall~i,j\in\mathbb N_0.$

(2) A metric space $X$ is cofinally complete if every cofinally Cauchy sequence in $X$ clusters.

(3) Let $X$ be a metric space and $x\in X.$ If $x$ has a compact neighbourhood set, $v(x)=\sup\{\epsilon>0:S_\epsilon[x]\text{ is compact}\},$ otherwise set $v(x)=0.$

**Main theorem 3.2: (1) X is cofinally complete $\implies$
(2) Whenever $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $X$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}v(x_n) = 0,$ then $(x_n)$ has a cluster point:**

Suppose condition (2) fails, and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}v(x_n) = 0$ that has no cluster point. Without loss of generality, we can assume by passing to a subsequence that $ν(x_n) < 1/n$ and so we can find a sequence $(w^n_j)$ in $S_{1/n}[x_n]$ with no cluster point. Partition $\mathbb N$ into an countable family of infinite subsets $\{K_n: n\in\mathbb N\}.$ Then the assignment $y_j = w^j_n$ for $j\in K_n$ defines a ***cofinally Cauchy sequence*** $(y_j)$ in $X$ without a cluster point. Thus (1) fails.

> I have verified the theorem other than the fact that $(y_j)$ is cofinally Cauchy. Please tell me why $(y_j)$ is cofinally Cauchy?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: MathOverflow copy of the question: [Why $(y_j)$ is cofinally Cauchy?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/302909)

Comment: I should say that you have made (in my opinion) a good job in making the question readable without needing to read the linked paper. So +1 from me. (Maybe mentioning the suspected typo - which you already mentioned in comments under my answer - could be additional improvement of the question.)

Comment: Thank you for your support and cooperation

Comment: I can only guess why the somebody decided to downvote the question - since the downvoter did not leave any comment. One thing I can think of is that you only mentioned the possible typo in comments and this information is, somewhat relevant. Another possibility is that the downvoter simply does not like cross-posting.

Comment: For your own benefit you can have a look at discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting] on meta. [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5085#5088) offers some good advice. In a discussion on Meta MathOverflow it was suggested to [wait at least a week](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3457)

Comment: If this is the case then the downvote is justified. I could have been more careful while posting l.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This is the original version of the answer, which was posted based on [the original revision of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2821269/1) where we had $y_j=w^j_n$. See also some comments below this answer.

From the construction of the sequence $(y_j)$ you can see, that if $j\in K_n$ then you have $y_j\in S_{1/n}[x_n]$. So you have
$$d(y_i,y_j)<\frac 2n$$
for any $i,j\in K_n$. Since each $K_n$ is infinite (and thus cofinal in $\mathbb N$), you get that $y_j$ is cofinally Cauchy.

Comment: In the paper they have taken the sequence to be $(w^n_i)$ not $(w^i_n).$ Is it a printing mistake?

Comment: @Jave Actually, the way it is written in the [current revision of your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2821269/4) and also in the paper it makes sense, as far as I can tell. I did not notice the discrepancy when posting the answer, sorry for that.

Comment: How does it make sense under the current revision?

Comment: I mean how can we show it cofinally Cauchy under current revision

Comment: @Jave in the paper it's written as $(w^n_j)$, where this sequence has $n$ fixed and $j$ running as the sequence parameter.

Comment: But when j’s are taken from same K_n their corresponding y_j may lie on different closed ball having different centre

Comment: Sorry @Jave, I am not able to resolve this now. (But I agree with you that it seems that this way there might be a problem.) I have some other stuff to attend to IRL. If I have time later, I'll try to get back to this. (Well, unless somebody else answers you in the meantime.)

Comment: At least by taking $y_j=w^j_n$ as written in the original version of the question we can say such a sequence can be found which is cofinally Cauchy but does not clusters. Right?

Comment: @Jave My best guess is that we have to use $y_j=w^n_j$, I have left a few comments on this [here in general topology chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/15201/2018/6/16). Feel free to ping me there if there further clarifications are needed.